# Quill editor + VueJS2 image upload: Base64 image to URL

Tags: javascript, image, vuejs2, quill

Using editor from here: https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-quill-editor

I want to save images from Quill editor to MySQL database, but bigger images in base64 are too long to insert.

I tried to write custom image handler, so that it auto uploads image to server and server returns image URL but now I'm stuck.

Here is my current HTML:

```
<quill-editor v-model="content"
    :options="editorOption"
    @onEditorBlur($event)"
    @onEditorFocus($event)"
    @onEditorReady($event)"
    @onEditorChange($event)">
</quill-editor>
```

Adding image handler to editor like this:

```
onEditorReady(editor) {
    editor.getModule('toolbar').addHandler('image', this.imageHandler);
    console.log('editor ready!', editor);
},
```

And my own handler:

```
imageHandler(image, callback){
    console.log(image); // Always true
    console.log(callback); // Always undefined

    // Should get image in here somehow..
    var sendData = {
        image: 'SomethingShouldBeInHere',
    };

    // Send image to server, 
    //  Server will return link to image
    axios.put('/testImageUpload', sendData)
    .then(function(cbData) {
        // In here should add image tag to editor somehow..

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
},
```

I tried this: [Add support for custom image handler](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/pull/995)
But it doesn't work, since image is always true and callback is undefined.

Tried this too: [Quill `imageHandler` Demo](http://codepen.io/jackmu95/pen/EgBKZr)
It has same problems first link.

Currently server is hardcoded to return "http://localhost/images/php.jpg"

If possible I would not use any libraries (jQuery, dropzone, etc)

I thought I can perhaps check if image was inserted in onEditorChange(), then send request to server, get URL, search for this base64 in editor and replace it with URL, but it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

set handlers in your options like this

```js
editorOption: {
  modules: {
   toolbar: {
    container: [['image'], ...],
    handlers: {
     'image': function(){
      document.getElementById('getFile').click()
     }
    }
   } 
  }
}


methods: {
  uploadFunction(e){
  
    //you can get images data in e.target.files
    //an single example for using formData to post to server
    
    
    var form = new FormData()
    form.append('file[]', e.target.files[0])
    
    //do your post
    
    
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <quill-editor v-model="content"
            :options="editorOption"
            @change="oneEditorChange($event)">
  </quill-editor>
  <input type="file" id="getFile" @change="uploadFunction($event)" />
</template>
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? Where to set these handlers, maybe?

Comment: Got it working, thanks! Never thought to add another input and use it =)

Comment: Please can you direct me on how I can take off image and video upload from this editor, I am implementing it in my project and I need just the basic text editing features. Thanks

Comment: @Benjiro you can set a custom toolbar witch only contains the functions you want, just cover the default setting. https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/

Answer (score 3):

This my source code....

```
//Template
<input type="file" @change="uploadFunction" id="file" hidden>

<quill-editor 
      v-model="model" 
      :options="editorOption" 
      ref="quillEdit">
</quill-editor>
```

and script

```
 //script
    import "quill/dist/quill.core.css";
    import "quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
    import "quill/dist/quill.bubble.css";
    import Quill from "quill";
    import { quillEditor } from "vue-quill-editor";
    import ImageResize from "quill-image-resize-module";
    import axios from '~/plugins/axios'

    export default {
      data() {
        model: '',
        selectedFile : '',
        editorOption: {
            // some quill options
            modules: {
              toolbar: {
                container: [["bold", "image"]],
                handlers: {
                  image: function() {
                    document.getElementById('file').click()
                  }
                }
              },
              imageResize: {
                modules: ["Resize", "DisplaySize", "Toolbar"]
              }
            }
          },
       },
       methods: {
        uploadFunction(e){
             this.selectedFile = e.target.files[0];

          var form = new FormData();
          form.append("file", this.selectedFile);
          form.append("name", this.selectedFile.name);

            //upload image to server
            axios.post('media-save', form,{
             'headers': {
                 'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"
              }
             })
            .then(r => {
              console.log('success')

              //this code to set your position cursor
const range = this.$refs.quillEdit.quill.getSelection()
//this code to set image on your server to quill editor
              this.$refs.quillEdit.quill.insertEmbed(range.index , 'image', `http://your.api/${r}`)
            })
            .catch(e => {
              console.log('error')
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: `insertEmbed(range, ...`  range is an object. So should be `range.index`

Comment: @Shirker thank you for correcting, but now I realize that if the data is an object then the image will be placed in the last paragraph, so that I have never been disturbed before ... :D

Comment: i've also heard its safer to call `..quill.focus()` before `getSelection()` 
Another thing in my case `this.$refs.quillEdit.quill` will be `this.$refs.quillEdit[0].quill` since $refs returns array

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// ** Reactstrap Imports
import {
    Row,
    Form,
    Modal,
    ModalHeader,
    ModalBody,
    Col
} from 'reactstrap'

import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'

import { useQuill } from 'react-quilljs';

import 'quill/dist/quill.snow.css'

export default function ReadingModal({ open, handleModal, datas })
{

    const { t } = useTranslation()

    const [ News, setNews ] = useState(datas || '')

    return (
        <Modal isOpen={open} toggle={handleModal} className="modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" onClosed={handleModal}>
            <ModalHeader className='bg-transparent pb-0' toggle={handleModal} ></ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody className="px-sm-3 pt-30 pb-3">
                <div className='text-center'>
                    <h4>{News && News['title']}</h4>
                </div>
                <Row tag={Form} className="gy-1">
                        <Col>
                            {News && News['body']}
                        </Col>
                </Row>
            </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
    );
};
```